# Choose which button appears in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have an activity A and an activity B. I can access to activity B by two differents ways in activity  A : By clicking on the add button, or by clicking the option modify of my ContextMenu of my ListView.

Here's the deal : If I click in the Add button, I want to add something to that listView, but if I click in Modify, I want to modify the value of the row.

But, when I get to that activity B, both buttons appear in the toolbar. **But I only want the Add Button if I clicked in add in activity A. And I want the Refresh/Update button if I clicked in Modify.**

I can already check which way I used to get to Activity B, but I don't know how to hide the other button, depending the way I chose.

Here's my menu :

```
<item

    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:title="Save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_update"
    android:title="Update"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_update"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
/>
```

And here's the code on the Activity B :

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_addcours_notes, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_save:

            cours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETCours);
            String nom_cours= cours.getText().toString();

            TextView tv_cours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCours);

            if(nom_cours.length()<=0 || nom_cours.length()<3)
            {
                Toast ok = Toast.makeText(AjoutCours.this, "Veuillez insérer un nom pour votre cours (minimum 3 caractères).", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                ok.show();
                tv_cours.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            else
            {
                Cours c = new Cours();
                c.setCours(nom_cours);
                dbhelper.Open();
                dbhelper.insertCours(c);

                Intent a = new Intent(AjoutCours.this, AffichageCours.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.action_update:
            Intent intent = this.getIntent();
            String nomcours = intent.getExtras().getString("cours_nom");
            EditText cours =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETCours);
            String newcours = cours.getText().toString();
            dbhelper.Open();
            dbhelper.updateCours(newcours,nomcours);
            Intent retour = new Intent(AjoutCours.this,AffichageCours.class);
            startActivity(retour);
        return true;
```

Here's how I make the difference in activity B (I getExtras from activity A):

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(intent != null)
    {
        String option = intent.getExtras().getString("cours");
        if(option.equals("ajouter"))
        {

        }
        if(option.equals("modifier"))
        {
            String nomcours = intent.getExtras().getString("cours_nom");
            EditText _nomcours=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETCours);
            _nomcours.setText(nomcours);
        }
    }
```

Tell me if you need more code !

Thank you !

Comment: you can use onprepareOptionmenu to hide/unhide menu as per your need

Comment: how do I use it ?

Comment: you pass some string with intent right? then for example pass add as putExtra and in your onprepareoptionmenu() method check if string.equals=add then hide other button

Comment: You could set the buttons visibility to invisible or gone; like btnAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or btnAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);
      MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_update);
     if(option.equals("ajouter"))
        {
        item.setVisible(true);
         item2.setVisible(false);
        }else{
         item.setVisible(false);
        item2.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: is it a void method ? cus I'm getting an error there

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out. It's a boolean method and I had forgotten the return true. But thank you ! Accepted answer !